# What was Paul trying to achieve by lying to his wife in the final episode of the first season?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-fall-tv

When Sally Ann confronted Paul in *The Fall* S01E05 about the real reason of his late night absences  in home he lied to her about having an affair with Katie.
In my understanding he (later) started the affair to have a complex alibi, hoping to pretend to be some kind of an anti-police anarchist and not a killer.

Still I don't understand why he told her wife that the affair was already ongoing, risking a destruction of his family, something that he seemed to genuinely care about.
Was it a complicated scheme to have Katie cover up for him and give him alibi for the killing nights?

If so, this didn't really go well, because:

- Katie gave him alibi anyway, without knowing about the fake affair
- She was angry at him for "inventing" the affair

Additionally, for this scheme, he really didn't have to lie to Sally Ann about having the affair, he just needed to seduce Katie and then she would lie to the police for him anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just watched series 1 of the Fall and when Paul tells Sally-Ann he has been having an affair with Katie I did wonder about the reasoning. My take on it is that Paul will do absolutely anything to hold onto his secret and knowing Katie is infatuated with him, he invents the affair and feeds this story to Sally-Ann. I agree that he seems to genuinely care about his wife and kids but his priority is keeping the secret - he will do anything to protect that.